# jQuery UI: How can I send a set of common options to .dialog()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Is it possible to send a set of common options:

```
var commonVars = {
    autoOpen:       false,
    draggable:      false,
    resizable:      false,
    show:           'fade',
    hide:           'fade'
};
```

To dialog boxes:

```
$('#dialog_1').dialog({
    //Common vars go here somehow
    width:          275,
    height:         170,
    dialogClass:    "class1 class2"
});
$('#dialog_2').dialog({
    //Common vars go here somehow
    width:          600,
    height:         350,
    dialogClass:    "class3 class4"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, kind of on accident. So for anyone wondering the same thing, you can put the `commonVars` variable before each dialog's options bracket:

```
var commonVars = {
    autoOpen:   false,
    draggable:  false,
    resizable:  false,
    show:       'fade',
    hide:       'fade'
};

$('#dialog_1').dialog(commonVars,{
    width:          275,
    height:         170,
    dialogClass:    "class1 class2"
});
```

Answer (score 5):

[$.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)

Example:

```
var object1 = {
    //Common vars go here somehow
    width:          275,
    height:         170,
    dialogClass:    "class1 class2"
};

var object2 = {
//Common vars go here somehow
width:          600,
height:         350,
dialogClass:    "class3 class4"
}
var commonVars = {
    autoOpen:       false,
    draggable:      false,
    resizable:      false,
    show:           'fade',
    hide:           'fade'
};

$.extend(object1, commonVars);
$.extend(object2, commonVars);

$('#dialog_1').dialog(object1);
$('#dialog_2').dialog(object2);
```

Comment: +1 ... although, in my cases, I use the format of `if (typeof object1 === 'object') { object1 = $.extend(commonVars, object1); } else { object1 = commonVars; }` for protection.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do `$('#dialog_1').dialog(commonVars)`?